# Creating a form with jQuery, session vars gone after normal submit

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, session, session-variables

I have the following jQuery js to insert a form in my view (in application.js):

```
$("#add_new_quote").click(function() {
    $(".quote:first").prepend("<form action=\"" + window.location + "\" accept-charset=\"UTF-8\" method=\"post\"> " +
        "Quote: <input id=\"quote_text\" name =\"quote_text\" type=\"text\" maxlength='145' size='100'>" +
        "<input name=\"submit\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Add\">" +
        "</form>" +
        "<br>");
});
```

When I click submit, all session vars I have set are somehow lost, and I have no idea why and how. For example, I'm setting user's id in a session variable (session[:user_id]) for references, and it is blank after the submit. I tried adding a form using form_tag in the view, and it works fine, so I guess I'm missing something important ...

I'm using Rails 3 and jQuery 1.5.

Comment: Have you tried a hard-coded HTML form? As in, a form written into the HTML and not generated by the JavaScript?

Comment: @Dimitry Yes, I was just trying the same thing! I created the form using form_tag in the view, and then used jQuery to hide() it when the page loads; I can then show() the form and the submit works fine. That's good alternative to me, but I'm still curious what is clearing the session variables in my example above ... Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: All that comes to mind is a browser security feature preventing generated forms from submitting session data. But this seems very unlikely. Please, try removing the action and accept-charset form attributes and submit the form again.

Comment: Compare the HTML that `form_tag` produces with what you're doing in jQuery, `form_tag` may be adding extra hidden form elements.

Comment: @mu-is-too-short Checked both forms - they are exactly the same in code, but when I had a look at the log file, I noticed that Rails is actually adding an authenticity token to the form_tag POST. The auth token is missing when I submit the form I inserted with jQuery, so I suspect it is indeed a security mechanism in Rails, as @Dimitry suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently when I submit the hand-crafted form with jQuery, Rails does not add the authenticity token to the POST parameters, therefore the "problem" is probably caused by a security feature in Rails which clears the session. An alternative is to use form_tag to create the form in the view, use jQuery to hide() it when the page loads, and use toggle() to unhide/hide the form when the user clicks on a link or button. Thanks to Dimitry and moo-is-too-short for their help.

Answer (score 1):

if you add this it will set the CSRF token...

```
// ahead of the form string
var token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');

// then in the form string
"<input name='authenticity_token' type='hidden' value='" + token + "'/>"
```

That should fix the problem if you can't use AJAX which will do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to serialize your form and submit it by ajax.

http://api.jquery.com/serialize/